# PHP shell_exec not working

Tags: php, shell, sweave

I'm trying to run a shell script on my MacOSX, but it's not working.
My report.sh file calls another .sh file (Sweave.sh) that is stored in /usr/local/bin.

```
<?php

shell_exec("./report.sh");
echo "Hello 123";

?>
```

It print's 'Hello 123' on my browser, but report.sh is not doing it's job.
Why that happens? Here's report.sh:

```
# !/bin/bash
Sweave.sh -ld test_sweave.Rnw
```

If if call ./report.sh from the terminal, it works ok...thanks for any help!

EDIT: If i call ./report.php from the terminal, it says:

```
./report.php: line 2: ?php: No such file or directory
./report.php: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `"./report.sh"'
./report.php: line 4: `shell_exec("./report.sh");'
```

Comment: Use absolute paths for everything then try.

Comment: I already did, still nothing happens, and safe mode is off.

Comment: are you using apache? if so, has the apache user sufficient rights to execute your file?

Comment: Turn on error_report, and check the error.

Comment: @Andres - Yes, i'm using apache. Some days ago my php script was able to run exec(file.sh), but now it's not working...how do i set/see these configurations? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to run your script via command line you have to either:

a) start the file with this line

```
#!/path/to/php
```

b) run as:

```
php report.php
```

If that works, it could be due to permissions, since your web server runs under a different user than you.

Comment: Almost there. It runs on the terminal, thanks to your tip. But if i call my page from the browser, still not working.

Comment: @Fernando I'd place my money on permissions ... you can also add ` 2>&1` behind the script you're trying to execute to get some more details regarding the error.

Comment: Where do i put the  ` 2>&1` ? Thanks!

Comment: @Fernando `shell_exec("./report.sh 2>&1");`

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everyone for the comments, it was a *permission* issue.
I solved it by changing permissions for the 'Documents' folder of my server (i'm sure it's not the safest way, but i`m just testing anyway).

Just add rw access, be the owner and apply to enclosed items - thats it!

Answer (score 0):

`php -q report.php` will works without shebang (`#!/path/to/php`)